# Is there a way to have a string default to the names of the classes in the inheritance list

Tags: c#

Not exactly sure how to word this but say I have a few classes as follows

```
public class Item
{
    string itemPath;
    string prefabID;

    void Initialize()
    {
        itemPath = classnames + prefabID;
    }
}


public class Equippable : Item
public class Weapon : Equippable
public class MeleeWeapon : Weapon
```

I would like each string to end with its own class name beginning with the base classes name and have a '/' in between each name.

Just hoping to do this as a way of storing each items prefab path

so hopefully Equippable would have its string as

Item/Equippable/prefabID

Weapon would be

Item/Equippable/Weapon/prefabID

and so on for each derived  class...

any suggestions or workarounds on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
void Initialize()
{
    var segs = new List<string>();
    var type = GetType();
    while (type != null && type != typeof(object))
    {
        segs.Insert(0, type.Name);
        type = type.BaseType;
    }

    segs.Add(prefabID);

    itemPath = string.Join("/", segs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively iterate through all base types and build this path into itemPath.

Here is the implementation, and below is the output.

I think the field prefabID will be filled by you later on, so that whenever you call GetPrefabID() it will return itemPath + prefabID.

```
public class Item
{
    string itemPath;
    string prefabID;

    public string GetPrefabID()
    {
        return itemPath + "/" + prefabID;
    }

    public Item()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    void Initialize()
    {
        itemPath = GetPrefabPath() + prefabID;
        prefabID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    string GetPrefabPath()
    {
        StringBuilder prefabricatedPath = new StringBuilder(GetType().Name);
        Type baseType = GetType().BaseType;
        while (baseType != typeof(object))
        {
            prefabricatedPath.Insert(0, baseType.Name + "/");
            baseType = baseType.BaseType;
        }
        return prefabricatedPath.ToString();
    }
}


public class Equippable : Item { };
public class Weapon : Equippable { };
public class MeleeWeapon : Weapon { };

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("prefabID for Item: {0}", new Item().GetPrefabID());
    Console.WriteLine("prefabID for Equippable: {0}", new Equippable().GetPrefabID());
    Console.WriteLine("prefabID for Weapon: {0}", new Weapon().GetPrefabID());
    Console.WriteLine("prefabID for MeleeWeapon: {0}", new MeleeWeapon().GetPrefabID());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
prefabID for Item: Item/c4fb4f63-f7f1-4c83-9d01-26881bb5e014
prefabID for Equippable: Item/Equippable/858791ea-d10d-4560-b8e4-202d91625088
prefabID for Weapon: Item/Equippable/Weapon/0bcba546-df85-4fed-ab68-5a1e012df5d
prefabID for MeleeWeapon: Item/Equippable/Weapon/MeleeWeapon/75e60a6d-854a-4d07
b20b-a709699bb3d7
```

Comment: Oh.. It was too late. LOL